# Couchbase Delete document with Rest API

Tags: couchbase

I´ve been checking the Rest API and I cannot find an API to delete a particular document, or all documents of one particular view. Just the delete of the bucket or view.
Anyone know if is that possible?

Answer (score 5):

generally speaking the (official, supported) REST API will deal with the cluster and buckets, whereas key/value operations are handled through the `memcached` binary protocol, and the SDKs are here to give you a facade over all this (including k/v) in your language of choice, idiomatically.

tl:dr no at least not in a supported stable way, you should use one of the SDKs

Answer (score 0):

I can't find it either. Of course you could easily roll your own front-end wrapping a Couchbase client. Here's an example in ruby [this](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/couchbase-rest-api-rails).